Optimal transport - Monge plan - measure theoretic calculation
In my Optimal transport course we dealt with the Monge optimal transportation problem. We have:

some open sets $X, Y \subset \mathbb{R}^d$,

a cost function $c : X \times Y \rightarrow [0, +\infty ]$.


We try to find a  probability measure $\gamma: X \times Y \rightarrow [0, 1]$  that minimizes $ \int_{X \times Y} c(x,y) d \gamma(x,y)$ where $\gamma$ satisfies $d \gamma(x,y) = d \mu(x) \delta_{T(x)}(y) dy $ for some measurable map $T: X \rightarrow Y$. Here $\delta_{x}(A) = 1$, if $x \in A$ and $\delta_{x}(A) = 0$ otherwise is the usual Dirac measure.
My problem concerns this notation: $d \gamma(x,y) = d \mu(x) \delta_{T(x)}(y) dy.$ Our professor carries out the following calculation, for example:
For a set $B \subset Y, \int_{X \times B} d \gamma(x,y) = \int_{X} ( \int_{Y} 1_{B}(y) \delta_{T(x)}(y) dy ) d\mu(x).$
This looks like an application of Fubini/ Tonelli, but the measure we integrate with respect to is not the product measure on $X \times Y.$
So, how is this calculation justified? Is this just a weird way to write integration with respect to the pushforward measure $\mu *(T)$ (defined to be for any $B \subset Y$ $\mu *(T)(B) = \mu(T^{-1}(B))$) Is this an issue with notation or am I missing something?

Your professor just used Markov kernels without telling you. Otherwise you can take this formula for the definition of this measure (it could be a good exercise to show it is a well-defined measure)

@Will, thank you very much for the hint. Do you mean I should take the formula $\mu*(T)$ for the definition of this measure or the one further up with the integral for the marginal?

You can consider that $d\mu(x)\delta_{T(x)}(y)dy$ is the measure defined by $(d\mu(x)\delta_{T(x)}(y)dy)(A\times B)=\int_A\left(\int_B\delta_{T(x)}(y)dy\right)\mu(dx)$. You can check it is a well defined measure, and that it coincides with the concept of Markov kernel if you want to look it up.

@Will thanks again, this clarifies it. I wasn't sure if I'm supposed to take the integral expression as a definition or if it follows from a theorem in measure theory. $k(dy|x) = \delta_{T(x)}(dy)$ using the notation in Wikipedia satisfies the definition of Markov kernel and I'll try to prove that the expression defines a measure on the product space $X \times Y, \Sigma_{X} \otimes \Sigma_{Y}.$
